# SQL - JOINing table ON a=b AND c=b?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join

I am building a query from multiple tables and ran into implementations of JOIN statements that I don't fully understand...

As an example, I have these tables:

```
Applications AS a      - columns(ID, MemberName)
ContractAHistory AS ca - columns(ID, AppID, PolicyNumber)
ContractBHistory AS cb - columns(ID, AppID, PolicyNumber)
MemberPolicy AS m      - columns(ID, PolicyNumber)
```

And for clarity, there are two different kinds of Contracts (A and B) that each get assigned a PolicyNumber.

I would love to be able to do a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Applications a
FULL OUTER JOIN ContractAHistory ca ON a.ID=ca.AppID
FULL OUTER JOIN ContractBHistory cb ON a.ID=cb.AppID
FULL OUTER JOIN MemberPolicy m ON 
    (ca.PolicyNumber=m.PolicyNumber AND cb.PolicyNumber=m.PolicyNumber) 
WHERE m.PolicyNumber = 79301;
```

This hasn't worked for me, however, so I have settled on this:

```
SELECT * FROM Applications a
FULL OUTER JOIN ContractAHistory ca ON a.ID=ca.AppID
FULL OUTER JOIN ContractBHistory cb ON a.ID=cb.AppID
FULL OUTER JOIN MemberPolicy m1 ON ca.PolicyNumber=m1.PolicyNumber
FULL OUTER JOIN MemberPolicy m2 ON ca.PolicyNumber=m2.PolicyNumber
WHERE m1.PolicyNumber = 79301 OR m2.PolicyNumber = 79301;
```

Unfortunately, that means my WHERE clauses need to be more verbose:

```
... WHERE m1.PolicyNumber = 79301 OR m2.PolicyNumber = 79301;
```

instead of

```
... WHERE m.PolicyNumber = 79301;
```

Is it possible to achieve my ideal in this situation?  In the end, I desire to have the ability to use these all of these clean WHERE clauses on the properly constructed SQL query:

```
... WHERE a.MemberName = 'Annika Hansen';

... WHERE m.PolicyNumber = 79301;

... WHERE m.ID = 79;

... WHERE a.ID = 74656;
```

I am using SQL-Server, but I have tried to phrase this as a general question about SQL. Please let me know if I have been unclear - thank you in advance!

Here is an example with undesired results (thanks to @TheEsisia for most of this:)

```
declare @Applications table (ID int, MemberName varchar(30))
declare @ContractAHistory table (ID int, AppID int, PolicyNumber varchar(30))
declare @ContractBHistory table (ID int, AppID int, PolicyNumber varchar(30))
declare @MemberPolicy table (ID int, PolicyNumber varchar(30))

Insert Into @Applications Values
 (1, 'AA')
,(2, 'BB')
,(3, 'CC')
,(4, 'DD')

Insert Into @ContractAHistory Values
  (1, 1, 'A')
 ,(2, 2, 'B')

Insert Into @ContractBHistory Values
 (1, 3, 'H12007')
,(2, 4, 'GT31')

Insert Into @MemberPolicy Values
 (1, 'A')
,(2, 'B')
,(3, 'H12007')
,(4, 'GT31')

SELECT * FROM @Applications a
FULL OUTER JOIN @ContractAHistory ca ON a.ID=ca.AppID
FULL OUTER JOIN @ContractBHistory cb ON a.ID=cb.AppID
FULL OUTER JOIN @MemberPolicy m ON 
(ca.PolicyNumber=m.PolicyNumber AND cb.PolicyNumber=m.PolicyNumber)
WHERE m.PolicyNumber = 'GT31';
```

**Update:** @TheEsisia helped me see that replacing the AND with an OR in the last query there achieves my desired results.  But answering @ThorstenKettner's questions: I certainly may not need all the FULL OUTER JOINs - however, I do want to pull up all information based on a specific WHERE clause. I can get requests for information with only one piece of the puzzle, so I'd like to pull up everything based on only an m.ID or an AppID or a PolicyNumber. For efficiency, I'm hoping to use the same primary query and only change the WHERE clause appropriately.  Also, each PolicyNumber matches to one Member and one Contract (either A or B) and one a.ID. That is where the complexity comes in: I never know from the PolicyNumber which kind of Contract it is. I hope that helps to clear up a bit about my use cases. Thanks to all.

Comment: why do you say that the query that *you would love to use* is not allowed?

Comment: `I realize that is not allowed` - why do you think that?  It looks perfectly valid to me...

Comment: Have you tried adding `m1.PolicyNumber = m2.PolicyNumber` to your where clause? That should work, but I can't test it at the moment.

Comment: The predicates in your where clause that reference outer joined tables will turn the joins into INNER joins!

Comment: Siyual and Lamak - you are correct, it is valid SQL (I have amended my post accordingly), but it is not returning the desired results - perhaps because of what @LordPeter mentioned...

Comment: @LHM It would be best if you post some sample data and desired result

Comment: @RobbieToyota, you mean like this: `... WHERE m.PolicyNumber = 79301 AND m1.PolicyNumber = m2.PolicyNumber` ?  That is interesting and works, but is not as concise as I thought it could be.

Comment: If you want the filter's to be applied independent of the joins, then you need to move the limiting where clause criteria to the joins for all but the 1st table

Comment: @xQbert - can you show me using the "GT31" WHERE clause in my question? Thanks!

Comment: What do you expect to see? Obviously the condition: ca.PolicyNumber=m.PolicyNumber AND cb.PolicyNumber=m.PolicyNumber is never satisfied as in this example. m.PolicyNumber = 'GT31' cannot be found in ca.PolicyNumber. That's why there are NULLs, but you still see the values for m.ID and m.PolicyNumber.

Comment: @LHM should just be... `SELECT * FROM @Applications a
FULL OUTER JOIN @ContractAHistory ca ON a.ID=ca.AppID
FULL OUTER JOIN @ContractBHistory cb ON a.ID=cb.AppID
FULL OUTER JOIN @MemberPolicy m ON 
ca.PolicyNumber=m.PolicyNumber AND cb.PolicyNumber=m.PolicyNumber
AND m.PolicyNumber = 'GT31'`  M.policyNumber will be filtered to just GT31 and the remainder of the full outer join values will remain as the filtering is done before the joins.

Comment: Do you really need all those full outer joins? That would mean that `AppID` and `PolicyNumber` can be null in the history tables and you still want to see all history records and all app records and all policy records. Really? That sounds weird.

Comment: Another thing: There can obviously be many ca records for an app and many cb records, too. So say you have four ca records for an app and five cb records. The join gets you 4*5=20 rows. What information does that give you? What does the third ca have to do with the fourth cb for instance? To me this looks strange and maybe you'd like to rethink what the query shall show.

Comment: Okay, you have a policy number. This number uniquely identifies one policy record. Correct? And you say this one policy record is connected with excatly one contract, which can either be an A contract or a B contract. Yes? Why are there two different contract tables? One would usually strive to avoid this. Do the two contract types have very different columns?

Comment: I agree - this table set-up is not ideal.  But I'm working with an established codebase/database.  Refactoring the set-up is not an option right now.

Comment: Oh, and yes, @ThorstenKettner, the two contract types have different columns - but they may have enough overlap that I could still use the UNION that you suggest below...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how we should access the tables:

1. With a policy number we find the policy record.
2. Linked to that record is either an A contract record or a B contract record. So we must outer join these tables.
3. Then we want the application for the contract found. This can be done with an inner join, because we always expect a match. (We don't want contracts without a matching application entry. Or, in case we do, switch this to a left outer join)

The complete query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM @MemberPolicy m
LEFT OUTER JOIN @ContractAHistory ca ON ca.PolicyNumber = m.PolicyNumber
LEFT OUTER JOIN @ContractBHistory cb ON cb.PolicyNumber = m.PolicyNumber
INNER JOIN @Applications a ON a.ID IN (ca.AppID, cb.AppID)
WHERE m.PolicyNumber = 'GT31';
```

In case the contracts are very similar, you could also union the two tables. (But in that case it might be much better to change the database design and makes this one table only for the two contract types to start with.) In this situation we don't need any outer join; we select the policy, its contract and its application:

```
SELECT * 
FROM @MemberPolicy m
INNER JOIN 
(
  SELECT PolicyNumber, title, description, client, a_only_col, null as b_only_col
  FROM @ContractAHistory
  UNION ALL
  SELECT PolicyNumber, title, description, client, null as a_only_col, b_only_col
  FROM @ContractBHistory
) c ON c.PolicyNumber = m.PolicyNumber
INNER JOIN @Applications a ON a.ID = c.AppID
WHERE m.PolicyNumber = 'GT31';
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why you say "This hasn't worked for me", because it works for me:

```
declare @Applications table (ID int, MemberName varchar(30))
declare @ContractAHistory table (ID int, AppID int, PolicyNumber varchar(30))
declare @ContractBHistory table (ID int, AppID int, PolicyNumber varchar(30))
declare @MemberPolicy table (ID int, PolicyNumber varchar(30))

Insert Into @Applications Values
 (1, 'AA')
,(2, 'BB')
,(3, 'CC')
,(4, 'DD')

Insert Into @ContractAHistory Values
 (1, 1, 'A')
 ,(2, 2, 'B')


Insert Into @ContractBHistory Values
 (1, 2, 'H12007')
,(2, 3, 'GT31')

Insert Into @MemberPolicy Values
 (1, 'WW2007')
,(2, 'LL2009')
,(3, 'JJ2010')
,(4, 'RR2009')


SELECT * FROM @Applications a
FULL OUTER JOIN @ContractAHistory ca ON a.ID=ca.AppID
FULL OUTER JOIN @ContractBHistory cb ON a.ID=cb.AppID
FULL OUTER JOIN @MemberPolicy m ON 
(ca.PolicyNumber=m.PolicyNumber AND cb.PolicyNumber=m.PolicyNumber)
```

**UPDATE**

If your original problem is exactly like this one, then, you neither need an `AND` nor an `OR`. You do not need to have the left side of that condition:

```
declare @Applications table (ID int, MemberName varchar(30))
declare @ContractAHistory table (ID int, AppID int, PolicyNumber varchar(30))
declare @ContractBHistory table (ID int, AppID int, PolicyNumber varchar(30))
declare @MemberPolicy table (ID int, PolicyNumber varchar(30))

Insert Into @Applications Values
 (1, 'AA')
,(2, 'BB')
,(3, 'CC')
,(4, 'DD')

Insert Into @ContractAHistory Values
  (1, 1, 'A')
 ,(2, 2, 'B')

Insert Into @ContractBHistory Values
 (1, 3, 'H12007')
,(2, 4, 'GT31')

Insert Into @MemberPolicy Values
 (1, 'A')
,(2, 'B')
,(3, 'H12007')
,(4, 'GT31')

SELECT * FROM @Applications a
FULL OUTER JOIN @ContractAHistory ca ON a.ID=ca.AppID
FULL OUTER JOIN @ContractBHistory cb ON a.ID=cb.AppID
FULL OUTER JOIN @MemberPolicy m ON 
cb.PolicyNumber=m.PolicyNumber
WHERE m.PolicyNumber = 'GT31';
```

Note: its still possible that your original query might need `OR`, but nobody can tell you that unless we know what it is that you are going to acheive.

Click on this link to play with the query: [link](http://rextester.com/live/QQSGEH85333)

Comment: (Amending dataset to match my implementation)  Adding the WHERE clause to your query returns many NULLs.   
Replace everything from this line and following:
`Insert Into @ContractBHistory Values
 (1, 3, 'H12007')
,(2, 4, 'GT31')
Insert Into @MemberPolicy Values
 (1, 'A')
,(2, 'B')
,(3, 'H12007')
,(4, 'GT31')
SELECT * FROM @Applications a
FULL OUTER JOIN @ContractAHistory ca ON a.ID=ca.AppID
FULL OUTER JOIN @ContractBHistory cb ON a.ID=cb.AppID
FULL OUTER JOIN @MemberPolicy m ON 
(ca.PolicyNumber=m.PolicyNumber AND cb.PolicyNumber=m.PolicyNumber) WHERE m.PolicyNumber = 'GT31';`

Comment: How you add the WHERE clauses? Can you post that amended query?

Comment: I added it to my question - hopefully the format is more clear.

Comment: What do you expect to see? Obviously the condition: `ca.PolicyNumber=m.PolicyNumber AND cb.PolicyNumber=m.PolicyNumber` is never satisfied as in this example. m.PolicyNumber = 'GT31' cannot be found in ca.PolicyNumber. That's why there are NULLs, but you still see the values for m.ID and m.PolicyNumber.

Comment: Of course!  Changing the condition to `ca.PolicyNumber=m.PolicyNumber OR cb.PolicyNumber=m.PolicyNumber` seems to get the behavior I am looking for!  I'll keep testing to be sure...

Comment: @LHM Check your original query and let us know what you see without `OR`.

Comment: Thanks, @TheEsisia - the OR is required for the Query to be versatile and work with other WHERE clauses - like `WHERE m.PolicyNumber = 'A';`...

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it is pretty straightforward. Create two identical tables A and B.

```
CREATE TABLE A (ID INT NULL, NAME VARCHAR(5) NULL)
CREATE TABLE B (ID INT NULL, NAME VARCHAR(5) NULL)

--TABLE A
INSERT A 
SELECT 1, 'John'
UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'Henry'

--TABLE B
INSERT B 
SELECT 1, 'John'
UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'Henry'

--scenario #1:
SELECT * 
FROM A
LEFT JOIN B
ON A.ID = B.ID AND B.NAME = 'Henry'

--scenario #2:
SELECT * 
FROM A
LEFT JOIN B
ON A.ID = B.ID
WHERE B.NAME = 'Henry'
```

As per scenario #1, both conditions `A.ID = B.ID` and `B.NAME = 'Henry'` will filter the tables A and B first before doing the left join.

[image]

As per scenario #2, conditions `A.ID = B.ID` will do the filter before the join, while condition `B.NAME = 'Henry'` will filter the full data set after doing the left join.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, @Dance-Henry,  so would adding parenthesis change how those work?  `... JOIN table ON a=b AND c=b WHERE b=x;
... JOIN table ON a=b AND c=b AND b=x;
... JOIN table ON (a=b AND c=b) WHERE b=x;
... JOIN table ON (a=b OR c=b) WHERE b=x;`

Comment: No it does not make any difference in this case.